# How to create a table with empty cells?

Tags: python, animation, manim, algorithm-animation

When using Manim, how to create a table such that in the first row there are letters of the word "HELLO", and in the second row there are empty cells?

Python code:

```
t3 = Table(
    [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]], include_outer_lines=True,
    line_config={"stroke_width": 5, "color": BLUE}, v_buff = 1.3).scale(0.8)

self.play(FadeIn(t3, run_time=2))
```

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick would be to set the cells of the empty row the same as the one above, but also change its opacity to `0`:

[image: Output]

```
from manim import *

class EmptyTableCells(Scene):
    def construct(self):

      t = Table(
      [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"],
      ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"]], include_outer_lines=True,
      line_config={"stroke_width": 5, "color": BLUE}, v_buff = 1.3).scale(0.8)

      t.get_rows()[1].set_opacity(0) # change the second row's text opacity
      self.play(FadeIn(t, run_time=2))
```